# Uploads to AWS failing from Safari 16

Tags: amazon-web-services, safari, upload, websocket

When I try to use Safari 16.x to upload iOS `.ipa` files to Amazon Web Services Device Farm for testing, the upload progress bar disappears before reaching 100% and AWS reports that its attempt to install the app on the device failed (as if the upload were corrupted). Safari's console reports "kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 55 - No buffer space available".

This happens even with extensions disabled. Other browsers (Firefox, Chrome) don't have this problem.

How can I get Safari to successfully upload these files to AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I can fix this problem by disabling "NSURLSession WebSocket" under "Develop > Experimental Features". This previously-experimental feature appears to now be enabled by default in Safari 16.

(To see Safari's Develop menu, enable it under "Safari > Preferences… > Advanced > [√] Show Develop menu in menu bar".)